# What is point of using the concatenation(+) in Python when commas(,) do the job?

Tags: python, concatenation

```
print("This is a string" + 123)
```

Concatenating throws error, but using a comma instead does the job.

Comment: That's only in the context of `print`. If you create a new variable `foo = 'Monty', 'Python'` and `foo = 'Monty' + 'Python'` do quite different things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already been told, your code raises an error because you can only concatenate two strings. In your case one of the arguments of the concatenation is an integer.

```
print("This is a string" + str (123))
```

But your question is more something *"plus vs. comma"*. Why one should *ever* use `+` when `,` works?

Well, that is true for `print` arguments, but actually there are other scenario in which you may need a concatenation. For example in an assignment

```
A = "This is a string" + str (123)
```

Using comma, in this case, would lead to a different  (and probably unexpected) result. It would generate a tuple and not a concatenation.

Comment: May I ask what you mean by syntactically invalid, cause doing this `A = "This is a string" , str (123)`. Would create a tuple right.

Answer (score 2):

Hey here you are trying to concatenate the string and integer. It will throw type error.
You can try something like

```
print("This is a string"+str(123))
```

Commas (,) are not actually concatenating the values it's just printing it in a fashion that it looks like concatenation.
Concatenation on the Other hand will actually join two strings.

Answer (score 1):

That's one case of `print()`. However if you do need a string, concatenation is the way:

```
x = "This is a string, "+str(123)
```

gets you `" This is a string, 123"`

Should you write

```
x = "This is a string", 123
```

you would get the tuple `("This is a string",123)`. That's not a string but an entirely different type.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your int value in a variable, you can print it out with f-string (format string).
Format take more inputs like `print(("one text number {num1} and another text number {num2}").format(num1=variable1, num2=variable2)`

```py
x = 123
print(("This is a string {x}").format(x=x))
```

The above code outputs:

```
This is a string 123
```

You can read more about it here:
[python-f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/)

Answer (score 0):

```
# You can concatenate strings and int variables with a comma, however a comma will silently insert a space between the values, whereas '+' will not. Also '+' when used with mixed types will give unexpected results or just error altogether.

>>> start = "Jaime Resendiz is"
>>> middle = 21
>>> end = "years old!

>>> print(start, middle, end)

>>> 'Jaime Resendiz is 21 years old!'
```

Answer (score -1):

It's simple cause `123` is an `int` type and you cannot `concatenate` `int` with `str` type.

```
>>> s = 123
>>> type(s)
<class 'int'>
>>>
>>> w = "Hello"+ s
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
>>>
>>>
>>> w = "Hello" + str(s)
>>>
>>> w
'Hello123'
>>>
```

You can see the error , so you can convert the `s` variable that its value is `123` to string using `str()` function. But situations like this that you want to concatenate strings with other types? I think you should use `f-strings`

**Example**

```
>>> boolean = True
>>> fl = 1.2
>>> integer = 100
>>>
>>> sentence = f"Hello variables! {boolean} {fl} {integer}"
>>> sentence
'Hello variables! True 1.2 100'
```